# Find the sum of two elements in a matrix

Tags: matrices

Given $[a_{ij}]_{10\times10}=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  1&2&4&7&...&...&...\\
  3&5&8&...&...&...&...\\
  6&9&...&...&...&...&...\\
  10&...&...&...&...&...&...&\\
  ...&...&...&...&...&...&...\\
  ...&...&...&...&...&...&98\\
  ...&...&...&...&...&99&100\\
\end{array}
\right]$, what's $a_{7,3}+a_{7,7}$?

Is there a better way than write down all the elements? It's not easy to find the formula of $a_{i,j}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix is in fact
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46\\
3&5&8&12&17&23&30&38&47&56\\
6&9&13&18&24&31&39&48&57&65\\
10&14&19&25&32&40&49&58&66&73\\
15&20&26&33&41&50&59&67&74&80\\
21&27&34&42&51&60&68&75&81&86\\
28&35&43&52&61&69&76&82&87&91\\
36&44&53&62&70&77&83&88&92&95\\
45&54&63&71&78&84&89&93&96&98\\
55&64&72&79&85&90&94&97&99&100\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
so the answer is $a_{7,3}+a_{7,7}=43+76=119$. In fact one can find that
$$a_{i,j}=\frac12i(i+1)+i+(i+1)+\dots+\min{(i+j-2,9)}+\overbrace{9+8+\dots+(21-i-j)}^{\text{if }i+j\gt11}$$
$$a_{i,j}=\begin{cases}\frac12i(i+1)+\sum_{k=i}^{i+j-2}k&&i+j\le11\\\frac12i(i+1)+\sum_{k=i}^9k+\sum_{k=21-i-j}^9k&&i+j\gt11\end{cases}$$
$$a_{i,j}=\begin{cases}\frac12i(i+1)+\frac12(i+j-2)(i+j-1)-\frac12i(i-1)&&i+j\le11\\\frac12i(i+1)+\frac12(9)(10)-\frac12i(i-1)+\frac12(9)(10)-\frac12(20-i-j)(21-i-j)&&i+j\gt11\end{cases}$$
$$a_{i,j}=\begin{cases}\frac12(i^2-i+j^2-3j+2ij+2)&&i+j\le11\\\frac12(-i^2+43i-j^2+41j-2ij-240)&&i+j\gt11\end{cases}$$
So the sum would be
$$\begin{align}
a_{7,3}+a_{7,7}
&=\frac12(7^2-7+3^2-3(3)+2(7)(3)+2)+\frac12(-7^2+43(7)-7^2+41(7)-2(7)(7)-240)\\
&=43+76\\
&=119\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: The correct answer is 119

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected the formula/working.

Answer (score 0):

Let consider a general case of a $n\times n $ dimensional matrix with elements from $1$ to $n^2$ placed in the "antidiagonal" order. The andidiagonals of the matrix are assumed to be consequently numbered from $1$ (left-upper corner) to $2n-1$ (right-lower corner). As easy to see an element $a_{i, j}$ is located on $(i+j-1)$-th antidiagonal. Let $$k=i+j-1.$$ Then $$\forall k\le n:\; a_{i, j}=\frac {k (k-1)}2+i .$$

There is no need to compute an explicit expression for $k>n $, since due to symmetry
$$ a_{i, j}=n^2+1-a_{n+1-i, n+1-j}.$$

Therefore
$$a_{7, 3}=\frac {9\cdot8}2+7=43,\quad a_{7, 7}=100+1-a_{4, 4}=101-\left (\frac {7\cdot6}2+4\right)=76,
$$
So that the sum in question is $43+76=119$.