# $[a_{i,j}]_{n\times n}=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1&4&32&...\\ 2&16&...&...\\ 8&...&...&...\\ ...&...&...&...\\ \end{array}\right]$, find $a_{3,7}$

Tags: matrices

I found that $\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&4&32&...\\
2&16&...&...\\
8&...&...&...\\
...&...&...&...\\
\end{array}\right]=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
2^0&2^2&2^5&...\\
2^1&2^4&...&...\\
2^3&...&...&...\\
...&...&...&...\\
\end{array}\right]$

Is there a quicker way to find $a_{3,7}$ than write down all the elements? Maybe predict the elements near $a_{3,7}$ ?

The indices start at 1

Comment: Do the indices start at $0$ or $1$? The former implies $a_{1,\,1}=16$, the latter $a_{1,\,1}=1$.

Comment: Assume indices start at $1$, $\log_2 a_{ij} = \frac{(i+j-1)(i+j-2)}{2} + (j-1)$

Comment: @J.G. It start at $1$.

Comment: @achillehui Your answer is correct, it's $2^{42}$. How did you come up with that formula?

Comment: @David look at mankind's answer, my logic is about the same as his (I have verified the answer is $2^{42}$ by explicitly construct the matrix in a CAS).

Comment: Another version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214410/find-the-sum-of-two-elements-in-a-matrix).

Comment: The answer is independent of $n$ only if $n\ge10$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All elements on a right to left downward diagonal have indices adding to the same number. For instance, $a_{1,2}$ and $a_{2,1}$ are on the same diagonal and their indices add to three.

The element $a_{3,7}$ is on the diagonal with elements whose indices add to 10. This means there are $1+2+\cdots+8=36$ elements before $a_{9,1}$, which is thus $2^{36}$.

Then the sought after element is 6 elements after this one, i.e. $2^{42}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would establish how the exponents increase as you move to the right along row $3.$ First, $2^3,$ then $2^7,$ then $2^{12}.$ Do you see a pattern? If not, you might want to think about how it progresses along the first two rows, as well. In the first row, we have $2^0,2^2,2^5,2^9,2^{14};$ in the second, $2^1,2^4,2^8,2^{13}.$

---

**Added**: As you've already accepted an answer, I'll go ahead and elaborate. The first entry in row $3$ is $2^3,$ next is $2^{3+4},$ then $2^{3+4+5},$ and so on. Thus, the seventh term is $2^{3+4+5+6+7+8+9}=2^{42}.$

Answer (score 0):

**General formula** is: 
$$\log_2a_{i,j}=\frac{i(i-1)}{2}+\frac{(2i+j)(j-1)}{2}.$$

**Derivation:** The exponents of $a_{i,1}$ are [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number): $$0,1,3,6,...,\frac{i(i-1)}{2}.$$

The exponents of $a_{i,j}$:
$$\underbrace{\frac{i(i-1)}{2}}_{a_{i,1}},\underbrace{\frac{i(i-1)}{2}+(i+1)}_{a_{i,2}},...,\underbrace{\frac{i(i-1)}{2}+(i+1)+\cdots +(i+j-1)}_{a_{i,j}}=\\
\frac{i(i-1)}{2}+\frac{(i+1)+(i+j-1)}{2}\cdot (j-1)=\\
\frac{i(i-1)}{2}+\frac{(2i+j)(j-1)}{2},$$
which is the same as achille hui's answer in the comment above.